# Prevent application of a class in jquerymobile

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

How can I force `ui-btn-active` never to be set anywhere? Listening for events seems very bloaty since I don't really know where it is applied.

Searching online I only found very outdated solutions.

Comment: There's no event used to detect when a class is applied

Comment: I could listen for click events or something, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the class in [JS](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/cb9112abb3acf73abc104051ac318647055b189c/js/defaults.js#L36) on [`mobileinit`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/mobileinit/)

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
   $.mobile.activeBtnClass = "";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Partly an answer..

You could overwrite the original `$.fn.addClass` method and remove the className before calling the original addClass:

```
var _org = $.fn.addClass;
$.fn.addClass = function(className) {

  className = className.replace(/\bui-btn-active\b/g, '');

  return _org.call(this, className);
}
```

This will not protect you against:

```
el.className = 'ui-btn-active';
$(el).html('<div class="ui-btn-active"></div>');
el.classList.add('ui-btn-active');
el.innerHTML = '<div class="ui-btn-active"></div>';
```